# How do I modify the whole screen buffer in windows (like f.lux)?

Tags: windows, framebuffer

I'm playing a practical joke on my work colleague, basically I want to write a program which modifies the final windows screen buffer in the same way that f.lux does, except instead of changing the color temp, I'm planning to apply a gradual gaussian blur.

I'm familiar with how to actually write the blur, but I've never done anything directly with the buffer for windows, so I'm just not sure how to read and write the whole thing.

I'll write it in whatever language is most convenient.

Comment: Hey, you ever figure this out or make any progress on it? I'm trying to figure out how to do the same. Preferably cross-platform, but either or is fine too.

Comment: I have not, sorry.